# How to reset password on Azure AD B2C user account using MSAL C#, .net core?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Is it possible to reset the user password created on my b2c tenant?

Trying to find something on the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview, but I couldn't find it. Maybe I am blind, so can someone point how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the password with [this Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

When updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: **Directory.AccessAsUser.All**.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = new User
{
    BusinessPhones = new List<String>()
    {
        "+1 425 555 0109"
    },
    OfficeLocation = "18/2111"
};

// If authorize without user, you need to add application permission. graphClient.Users[user-object-id].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
await graphClient.Me
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(user);
```